# How to configure Wampserver to act as a WebSocket proxy?

Tags: html, proxy, websocket, wampserver, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up a proxy server for a WebSocket chat app, but the client is telling me that it can't establish a connection to the proxy. I'm pretty new to WebSockets, so I have probably missed something.

My current setup is as follows:

- OS:  Windows 7 64-bit
- Proxy: localhost, port 6060. This uses Wampserver 2.5 with Apache 2.4.9, including the required modules (mod_proxy, mod_proxy_wstunnel)
- Destination server: localhost, port 8080. This uses Glassfish 4.0
- Server Endpoint: Java 1.7, configured to use Glassfish
- Client: HTML5 page with JavaScript

I've added the following lines to the httpd.conf file for WampServer:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:6060
Listen [::0]:6060
ServerName localhost:6060

# block anyone but localhost from accessing my computer's C: drive
<Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride none
   Order Deny,Allow     
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
   Require all denied
</Directory>

# set up a proxy on port 6060,forwarding any WebSocket requests to port 8080
<VirtualHost *:6060>
   ServerName proxyTestServer
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass            /ws/    ws://[IPADDRESS]:8080/Chatroom/chatroom/
   ProxyPass            /wss/   wss://[IPADDRESS]:8080/Chatroom/chatroom/
   ProxyPassReverse     /ws/    ws://[IPADDRESS]:8080/Chatroom/chatroom/
   ProxyPassReverse     /wss/   wss://[IPADDRESS]:8080/Chatroom/chatroom/
</VirtualHost>
```

The WebSocket in the client is defined as follows, using ordinary JavaScript:

```
chatSocket = new WebSocket("wss://[IPADDRESS]:6060");
```

Both Firefox 35 and Chrome 40 fail to connect to the proxy. This makes me suspect I've got the address wrong or configured the proxy incorrectly (although Wampserver does not show any errors). Like I said up at the top, I'm pretty new to WebSockets, so I might well have overlooked something.

**Update** (2nd of Feb 2015): after looking through the documentation on mod_proxy, I changed the configuration file so that the server and client communicate through port 80, along with the following. However, this has not worked.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass        /chatProxy/        ws://localhost:8080/ChatProxy/ChatProxy/
ProxyPassReverse /chatProxy/        ws://localhost:8080/ChatProxy/ChatProxy/
ProxyPass        /chatProxy/        wss://localhost:8080/ChatProxy/ChatProxy/
ProxyPassReverse /chatProxy/        wss://localhost:8080/ChatProxy/ChatProxy/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this as follows:

- Client hosted on my machine at port 6060.
- Backend server is a Java servlet (annotated as "ChatProxy") running through Glassfish on my machine at port 8080.
- Proxy server is on a different machine, which listens on port 6060.
- The client uses a *standard* WebSocket connection, i.e. `ws://ProxyIP:6060/chatProxy`

My proxy has the following configuration:

```
# The proxy listens to a specific IP address
Listen [ProxyIP]:6060
ServerName [ProxyIP]:6060   

<VirtualHost *:6060>

   ServerName proxyserver
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia On

   <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all          
   </Proxy>

   # anything on port 6060 which ends in /chatProxy will be redirected
   <Location /chatProxy>
      ProxyPass           ws://MyIP:8080/ChatProxy/ChatProxy
      ProxyPassReverse    ws://MyIP:8080/ChatProxy/ChatProxy

      # wss is similar, but obviously prefaced by wss instead of ws
   </Location>
</Virtual Host>
```

I'm not entirely sure why this works now, but I have noticed that it doesn't work if the client uses a WebSocketSecure connection. So, I probably haven't configured SSL properly, but I think I can figure that out later.